# Caesar's Cipher function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Caesar's cipher using python and this is how far I can get:

```
alphabet = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']

def create(shift):
    dictionary={}
    emptylist=[]
    int(shift)
    for x in alphabet:
        emptylist.append(x)
        code = ""
        for letters in emptylist:
            code = code + chr(ord(letters) + shift)
            dictionary[letters]=code
    return dictionary
```

It gets as far as getting me to put in my shift value but then prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    create(2)
  File "C:/Users/Pete/Documents/C- Paisley/A-Level/Computing/dictionarytolist.py", line 11, in create
    code = code + chr(ord(letters) + shift)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 26 found
```

The end product should be that it prints the shifted letters.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Any question at all would do to start.

Comment: Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You could start with telling us what is wrong and what part of that you don't understand.

Comment: What should it do? What does it do instead? How far did you get solving the problem? What did you narrow it down to? Etc.

Comment: It gets as far as getting me to put in my shift value but then prints:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    create(2)
  File "C:/Users/Pete/Documents/C- Paisley/A-Level/Computing/dictionarytolist.py", line 11, in create
    code = code + chr(ord(letters) + shift)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 26 found

Comment: is dictionary supposed to map from plaintext letters to cipher letters?

Comment: The end product should be that it prints the shifted letters

Comment: I've updated your question for you. You can edit your own question and add this information yourself too.

Comment: What does the error message tell you? (Specifically, the `TypeError:` and what follows it on the last line?

Answer (score 2):

a still simpler way is

```
def create(shift):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
```

Comment: this won't work if the string is something other than `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, for `'foo'`with `shift=1` it returns `'oof'`.

Comment: I thought we were just creating the cipher. that yields the cipher alphabet that corresponds to the plaintext alphabet (in retrospect, I should not have answered such an ill posed question)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this code for your cipher. It should be fairly self explanatory as to how it can be used.

```
>>> UPPER, LOWER = ord('A'), ord('a')
>>> def encode(text, shift):
    data = list(text)
    for i, c in enumerate(data):
        if c.isalpha():
            base = UPPER if c.isupper() else LOWER
            data[i] = chr((ord(c) - base + shift) % 26 + base)
    return ''.join(data)

>>> def decode(text, shift):
    return encode(text, -shift)

>>> encode('This is a test.', 0)
'This is a test.'
>>> encode('This is a test.', 1)
'Uijt jt b uftu.'
>>> encode('This is a test.', 2)
'Vjku ku c vguv.'
>>> encode('This is a test.', 26)
'This is a test.'
>>> encode('This is a test.', 3)
'Wklv lv d whvw.'
>>> decode(_, 3)
'This is a test.'
>>>
```